# Help with tri screen synergy setup

Tags: synergy

Ive recently discovered the mouse/keyboard sharing application synergy and have been trying to set it up. Install was relatively easy, however Ive run into a problem with my unusual setup.

[image]

So laptop 1 (host) is hard-wired to a monitor through a vga cable. The monitor is placed above the laptop screen so that when I move the cursor to the top of the laptop 1s screen it appears on the bottom of the monitor screen, using xrandr. This is where synergy comes in. I want to link laptop 1s screen with another laptop sitting to the right of it. When moving the cursor to the right hand edge of laptop 1 it does not transfer to laptop 2 (client) as intended (green arrow). However, after moving the cursor up to the Monitor, moving it to the right hand side of the monitor screen transfers it over to Laptop 2 via synergy (red arrow). Im wondering if there is anyway to have my cursor follow the green arrow path straight from laptop 1s screen to laptop 2 without having to go through the monitor.

Sorry, that was really convoluted. Ive googled around for answers but frankly I wasnt even entirely sure what terms to google. "VGA synergy" and "HDMI synergy" had the closest results but nothing that got the job done. I'd be happy to answer any clarifying questions as Im not sure I adequately explained the issue.

Xubuntu 14.10.10 on old Thinkpad running the latest version of synergy.

Answer (score 1):

The info you are looking for is located at http://synergy-project.org/wiki/Text_Config

Synergy considers your Laptop1 screen and the externally connected monitor as 1 screen.

Using monitors with different sizes/resolutions you have to do a little bit of calculating to get a smooth transition.
 Example:
  Laptop1 = 1024 x  768
  Laptop2 =  800 x  600
  Monitor = 1920 x 1080 
  Total vertical resolution of Laptop1 = 1848px
  600px (Laptop2) = 32% of 1848px

The minimal config file for this example would be:

```
section: screens
    Laptop1:
    Laptop2:
end

section links:
    Laptop1:
        right(68,100) = Laptop2
    Laptop2:
        left          = Laptop1(68,100)
end
```

This assumes the bottom of Laptop1 and Laptop2 are aligned. If e.g. Laptop2 is placed somewhat higher than Laptop1 you can adjust the percentages to e.g. (60,92) until you reach the desired result.
This also assumes Laptop1 and Laptop2 are the actual hostnames. If this isn't the case you can either replace in the above example Laptop1 and Laptop2 with the hostnames, or add this section to the config file and adjust the ip/hostname accordingly:

```
section: aliases
    Laptop1:
        ip/hostname 
    Laptop2:
        ip/hostname
end
```

Comment: Saw this in the review section. This seems pretty interesting, especially since I had this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed synergy from a `.deb` file or repository as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808419/use-synergy-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-16-04), you can use the command `synergy` to setup the layout of screens.

If it is the first time you run `synergy`, you can skip the registration process and select a "server installation". After that you can use an administration GUI to configure everything. Afterwards, every time you run `synergy`, you will get the administration GUI directly.

In the administration GUI, you can click on the `Configure Server...` button and configure the location of the screens of the other machines. You may check [more instructions](http://goinglinux.com/articles/UsingSynergyOnLinuxAndWindows_en.htm) in the internet.